# Sandcastle: How to reference own (non-msdn) HTML documentation?

Tags: reference, sandcastle

We use sandcastle to build our internal help. We have multiple teams working on parts of our solutions independently we need to document those independently. So we have i.e. a team creating component 1 and the help for it, and another team creating component 2 (which depends on component 1) and the help for it.

For easy access to the help is build and updated automatically as HTML help.
So we have the help for component 1 available on: http://internalserver/Components/Component1

Now the html help from Component 2 (will be deployed at: http://internalserver/Components/Component2) should be able to reference the classes in the HTML help for Component1.

How can we configure Sandcastle/Sandcastle help file builder to look in our help for our own components like it does at the MSDN for framework classes?